# Как в WPF вывести документ из sql server

Tags: wpf, sql-server

Есть таблица с полем для документа, тип данных varbinary(max)

И как вывести содержимое этого поля в WPF ?

Если картинку закинуть в это поле, я знаю как её вывести, а как сам документ ?

Comment: а что в документе хранится? что ты хочешь выводить? текст, звуки, картинки, видео?

Comment: @Pekor, в документе хранится текст и картинки.

Comment: могу предположить что надо во время выполнения программы в коде определять тип файла (картинка или текст) и выводить в нужный элемент (например в пикчербокс если картинка или в текстбокс если текст); либо возможно есть универсальный элемент для вывода и того, и того - советую поискать здесь (https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/15.php)

Comment: сначала не совсем понял, есть один документ, в нём находятся текст и картинки?

Comment: @Pekor, нет не один, документов будет много, но выводить я буду 1 для конкретной записи

Comment: понял, есть несколько документов которые хранятся в бд и эти документы содержат в себе текст и картинки, а ты хочешь выводить содержимое этих документов на какой-то элемент на форме?

Comment: @Pekor,x Да , содержимое документов. Выводить хочу на странице Page , типо пользователю выводится список книг в ListView , и возле каждой книге будет надпись (электронная версия) , и по нажатии выводится отдельная страница с содержимым документом.  Связать это все будет не проблема, проблема как содержимое документа вывести

Comment: почитай про `DocumentViewer`, возможно подойдет. И вот еще статья, наверное будет полезно https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/viewing-word-documents-in-wpf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выводить документ в элементе `DocumentViewer` + [статья](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/viewing-word-documents-in-wpf/) как можно преобразовать документ Word в XPS файл для `DocumentViewer'a`